# MySQL: sort so that the rows are brought together after column A but the groups odered after the greatest corresponding value in column B

Tags: mysql, sql

For a dummy example, let's say that I have a database with following rows: `book`, `author` (=column A), `publish-date` (=column B).

Now, I want to sort the books so that the rows are brought together by author, but the authors have to appear in such order that the author having published the most recently comes first. For each author the books have to be sub-sorted by publishing date.

Output example I would like to have:

```
BOOK            AUTHOR          PUBLISH-DATE    # COMMENT
some book       John Doe        2019            # most recent book => John Doe is first
another book    John Doe        2017
one more        John Doe        2011
again a book    Richard Roe     2016            # Richard Roe is second because this is the most recent book amongst the remaining ones.
and one more    Richard Roe     2008            
another one     Janie Doe       2013            # and so on.
```

(Explanation of the above example : John Doe comes first because he wrote a book most recently. But his other books are displayed immediately afterwards, sorted by publishing date in reversed order. Then comes Richard Roe because he is the second most recent author that published a book. And so on.)

Basically, instead of sorting with `ORDER BY author ASC, publish-date DESC`, I would like to reorder the groups of books by a given author after the biggest value in the third column.

I have no clue how to solve this in MySQL nor do I know how this kind of sorting is called. I hope you can help me out ^^ Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (select max(t2.publish_date)
          from t t2
          where t2.author = t.author
         );
```

MySQL 8+ (and standard SQL) has a much simpler method using window functions:

```
select t.*
from t
order by max(publish_date) over (partition by author)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must order first by each author's latest publishdate and then by publishdate descending:

```
select b.*
from books b
order by (
  select max(publishdate)
  from books
  where author = b.author
) desc, b.publishdate desc
```